# Paste[$\,$] does not paste the current system clipboard

Tags: front-end, linux

As described in the documentation, the [`Paste`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Paste.html) function,

> > `Paste[]` pastes the contents of the system clipboard in the input notebook.

But on my system, 10.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015), this does not work.  Here is what I find

- Open a new notebook with a fresh kernel, go to another program and copy some text, then go back to the notebook and evaluate `Paste[]`.  There is no output whatsoever.
- Now copy some text *out of the notebook*, and evaluate Paste[].  The output is what you copied.
- Now quit the kernel, leaving the front end open, and evaluate Paste[].  The output is the same as above.

So clearly it isn't pasting the contents of the system clipboard, but rather an internal front-end clipboard.  Has this always been the case?  Am I missing something in the documentation?  Is this the case on other versions?

Comment: Works for me on Win7 x64 with MMa 10.3.1. Probably it is OS-related issue.

Comment: This doesn't work for images in the clipboard.

Comment: @M.R. - I hadn't tried this before, but if I copy an image into the clipboard from my browser, then enter `Paste[]` I get nothing.  But if I first Ctrl-v paste it into the notebook, then afterwards `Paste[]` **does** work

Comment: Weird! Actually the image that get's copied is from a screenshot, then it doesn't work, was what I meant to say.

Comment: x windows clipboard doesn't work in any sensible way period. http://www.azquotes.com/quote/745472